# Accessing $nuxt inside a plugin?

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to access the $nuxt object inside a plugin?
My use case is that I want to run the "this.$nuxt.refresh()" method inside a plugin.
Tried

```js
export default async function ({
  $axios,
  redirect,
  app,
  $nuxt
}) {
  await $axios.onError(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.data.detail != null && error.response.data.detail.includes("Invalid token")) {
      app.$auth.strategy.token.reset()
      $nuxt.refresh() // This does not work, refresh is undefined
    }
  })
}
```

I also tried just importing Nuxt or accessing it from app.$nuxt.refresh() but still, none of these solutions seem to work. Is there an way to run refresh here or am I forced to use location.reload()?

E.g this does not work

```js
export default function ({ $auth, router, app }) {
    app.$nuxt.refresh() // Does not work
    app.nuxt.refresh() // Does not work
  }
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `app.refresh()`?
Since `app` should pretty much be `this` when using the context: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers

Comment: I believe I already tried this as mentioned in the question without it working :(, have you tried it yourself & checked if it works for you?

Comment: Could you please provide a [repro] if it's not working on your side? @Thorvald

Comment: I believe I tried this and it seems to me like the nuxt object is accessible inside app, but for some reason it's not possible to call refresh() on it. However when I tested this it was inside middlewares, but I believe I encountered the same problem in plugins. @kissu

Comment: @Thorvald do you have a repro for this one?

Comment: Sorry, no proper reprod available but the use case for me is that I got a middleware that checks if my nuxt auth tokens are set in the cookies. If $auth.loggedIn is false but the token strategy's token is not false, the other tabs were the login were not made on will reload to reflect the logged in state. Currently, I'm running a location.reload(), however ideally I'd want to try using a refresh instead.

Comment: @Thorvald not sure what is the issue here. A [repro] could be nice, otherwise, feel free to inspect the actual Nuxt instance in your devtools via `$vm0` as [shown here](https://youtu.be/Q8ze3EiOvps?t=1115). PS: I've already formatted your edit yeah (highlight).